# Where to get stock samsung galaxy images?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-3, factory-image

in particular I am looking at Samsung Galaxy S3 factory image. Samsung download site was useless.

Comment: [sammobile](https://www.sammobile.com/) is considered to be the go-to for this. Paying a fee will help in downloading faster. make sure you select the right device, region, language.There tools available on XDA that offer stock images too

Comment: this require paid subscription - not a best solution

Comment: If you don't want to pay and get from reliable source, search on XDA (not that they are unreliable but you never know)

Comment: Please note that questions asking us to find or recommend an app, device, ROM, accessory or off-site resource are off-topic for Android Enthusiasts.

Comment: @Izzy - I am not asking for any recommendation, I am asking where to find android resource for android phone. If you think this is off-topic for this forum, then your qualification as a moderator raises questions.

Comment: Dmitry, please read again: "asking us to find […] an app, device, ROM […] off-topic". You just asked us where to find galaxy images. That's off-topic here.

Comment: @Izzy - yet similar question from got 134 up votes from  community: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device?noredirect=1&lq=1 Whomever decided to include "ROM" into this rule is obviously lacking moderating capabilities. This is my point.

Comment: Yes, the one canonical question we keep so you don't have to go home empty-handed. So my point is: I've explained that in detail, you can cross-check that with our [Meta questions on this site's scope](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope), and especially read [this one](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/782/16575). No more discussion here.